# Learning Django unit testing

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I'm trying to get caught up on unit testing, and I've looked over a few books - Debugging Django, Web Dev. with Django, and the official docs, but none seem to cover unit testing thoroughly enough for me. I'm also not an expert in Python web development, so maybe that's why.

What I'm looking for is something that starts at an intermediate level of python skill/knowledge and covers Django unit testing from scratch, with a few good real-world examples.

Any recommendations on such resources? Much appreciated.

Comment: This might be better served on [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Question is if you already have any experience with unit testing. With any other enviroment, if you don't then probably this is why you don't get Django unit testing.

Comment: Minimal JUnit a while ago, for what that's worth... and @chrisaycock, should I re-ask this on Programmers? Or will someone migrate this for me

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Django-Testing-Debugging-Tracey-Karen/dp/1847197566/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1361288120&sr=1-1&keywords=django+testing

Comment: ^ I'm using the current release (1.4.3), should that make a difference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Reading

- [Test-Driven Django (by Harry Percival)](http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/) seems great to start with.
- [article testing django signals](http://blog.yourlabs.org/post/33004908819/testing-django-signals-properly) is also useful, many people have been doing signal testing wrong.

### Code

- [simple unit tests](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-rules-light/tree/master/rules_light/tests) that were made for TDD from [django-rules-light](http://django-rules-light.rtfd.org),
- [ugly selenium tests](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/blob/master/autocomplete_light/tests/widget.py) from [django-autocomplete-light](http://django-autocomplete-light.rtfd.org), if your selenium tests look like this then you've done it wrong (oh I'll redo them all right, [one day](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/issues/27) ...)
- interesting pattern in django-autocomplete-light: look how [AutocompleteTestCase](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/blob/master/autocomplete_light/tests/autocomplete/case.py) is the parent for [other tests](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/blob/master/autocomplete_light/tests/autocomplete/) ie. [this one](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/blob/master/autocomplete_light/tests/autocomplete/model.py) has no actual test code, it just generates data for the AutocompleteTestCase.
- [good selenium tests](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-session-security/blob/master/session_security/tests/script.py) from [django-session-security](http://django-session-security.rtfd.org). I'm happy with this one, not only is it readable, but the patterns used there allows the tests to run correctly even on very slow machines (ie. [travis-ci](http://travis-ci.org) free plan). Pay particular attention to [this change](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-session-security/commit/cf2aa92525c6e394bb7b5736aae0c46eac0295e5) which was the key, moving from a *wait for X seconds, then see if Y happened* pattern to *ensure that Y happened within X seconds* pattern. This IMHO makes better selenium tests.
- [ghost.py test example](https://gist.github.com/jpic/074a1a54181f50d578dc), but I think there was some bugs in my setup so I ended not using it, sounds worth trying anyway.

I'm sure you can find more on google/github/bitbucket/etc ...

### Useful apps

[djangopackages](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/testing/) has quite some useful "testing tool" apps.

Comment: This does it. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 4):

I've read quite a few Django books and Python books and you're right, none of them really gets the job done. The best material I have come across to date is Carl Meyer's Talk on [Testing and Django](https://pycon-2012-notes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/testing_and_django.html).

Comment: Nice! That's the style/content I like to see. Thanks

Comment: I don't think that Django unit tests documentation is done bad. For me it was easy to write Django tests when I moved from pure Python unit tests to Django unit tests. However my friend who didn't use before python unittests, couldn't get along with Django tests. So I think Django unittesting is documented well, but it doesn't cover basics behind unittesting, so it's confusing for people new to unit tests and TDD .

Comment: Carl Meyer's talk is great, I'd really recommend it as per @super9

Answer (score 0):

Did you try core developer Karen Tracy's book *Django 1.1 Testing And Debugging*? Although the title implies it's out of date, most of the advice is still applicable.